# auto-number equations in R markdown documents in RStudio

Tags: r, latex, rstudio, r-markdown, mathjax

I can auto-number mathjax equations in an R markdown document in RStudio by adding the following statement to the beginning of the Rmd document:

```
<script type="text/x-mathjax-config">
MathJax.Hub.Config({
  TeX: { 
      equationNumbers: { 
            autoNumber: "all",
            formatNumber: function (n) {return '9.'+n}
      } 
  }
});
</script>
```

The following also works, but not with the $$..$$ equations, only equations bracketed with \begin{equation}..\end{equation}.

```
<script type="text/x-mathjax-config">
MathJax.Hub.Config({
  TeX: { 
      equationNumbers: { 
            autoNumber: "AMS",
            formatNumber: function (n) {return '9.'+n}
      } 
  }
});
</script>
```

I can change the numbering to a static label with `\tag{mylabel}` inside the $$..$$, and the auto-numbering will skip that equation.

Unfortunately, to skip with no label add `\tag{}` results in the equation still labeled with ().

Does anyone know how to get rid of the empty brackets?

Does anybody know a *simple* statement to add to either the mathjax script statement or the $$..$$ equations within a Rmd doc that would add an auto-numbered Section number to the equation number?

most of the info from here: 
http://mathjax.readthedocs.org/en/latest/tex.html#automatic-equation-numbering

Thanks

Comment: Regarding your question on section number: I would have moved to Sweave long before that point came up instead of trying to emulate Latex behaviour in Markdown.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `\notag` or `\nonumber` on an expression to prevent an automatic tag from being applied to it.  So if you are using `autoNuber: "all"`, you can do

```
$$E=mc^2\nonumber$$
```

to get the equation with no number.